# Обратный transition-эффект при ховере до тех пор, пока анимация не закончится

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Хотел придумать так, чтобы сделать анимацию при ховере выполняющейся до тех пор, пока сама анимация закончится. То есть если подносить мышку туда-сюда к элементу, то анимация при обычном `transition` будет поддергиваться. Как сделать так, чтобы анимация шла игнорируя ховер до тех пор, пока она не примет конечное состояние? 
Сложность ещё в том, что тугглится класс в js. 
То есть `transition` сначала работает при вставке конкретного класса, а потом действует другой `transition` от селектора элемента, когда ховер на элементе заканчивается. Но это, возможно не важно, а может, ошибаюсь.
Я пробовал через таймеры решить эту задачу, но, видимо, совсем не туда копаю...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, мы создадим переменную, которая будет управлять, активен элемент или нет:

```js
var stopanimation = false;

$('div').mouseover(function() {
   
  if (!stopanimation) {//если анимация не выключена

    $(this).toggleClass('hover')
    stopanimation = true;//выключаем

    setTimeout(function() {
      stopanimation = false;//включаем после завершения анимации.
    }, 2000)

  }

})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  transition: all 2s;
}
div.hover {
  transform: translateX(200px);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Блин, такой принцип с переменной я пробовал, но почему-то у меня он не работал... Хотя три ночи тогда было, в чем-то ошибка была видимо. В принципе, сойдет, я думаю. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы писал через библиотеку jQuery использую .hover() http://www.wisdomweb.ru/JQd/hover.php
Можно также слушать события, и добавлять новые. Через CSS ты такое вряд ли реализуешь.

Comment: И что, что ховер в jQuery? Чем он отличаться будет от обычного ховера? Да я и тугглю классы этим же самым ховером, используя jQuery, только не сокращенной версией, а полной, потому что там нужно изменять область действия. Но это не важно. Это совершенно не ответ на вопрос. Я знаю, что не реализую через CSS, в вопросе не было про это сказано.

Comment: Toggle - просто переключает классы, Или отслеживает действия. Вам же я так понял надо следить за событиями.Пример-  Навел курсором мыши на какойто элемент, отработала одна функциия, убрал другая. Можно реализовать через mouseover/out https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave

Comment: Ну покажите в примере-то, я не понимаю, затем вопрос и задаю.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackStar1991/bwnu922a/ Оно ?

Comment: Не совсем: нужно, чтобы анимация продолжалась до конца и ховер игнорировался во время её выполнения, а потом опять включался.

Comment: Ну выше уже предложили решение, собственно.

Answer (score 0):

Мне понравился такой вариант создания управляемой анимации. Понравился тем, что можно вызывать разные события после окончания анимации и работать с анимацией нескольких элементов одновременно.

```js
var el = $('.box'),
  isAnimating = false;

el.hover(function() {
  animate();
});


function animate() {
  if (isAnimating) {
    return false;
  }

  isAnimating = true;

  el.addClass('active').on('animationend', function() {
    el.off('animationend');
    onEndAnimation();
  });
}

function onEndAnimation() {
  isAnimating = false;
}
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #d32d36;
}
.box.active {
  animation: moveToLeft 3.0s linear both;
}
@keyframes moveToLeft {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```